# Count all word including numbers in a php string

Tags: php

To count words in a php string usually we can use str_word_count but I think not always a good solution

#### good example:

```
$var ="Hello world!";
echo str_word_count($str);
print_r(str_word_count($str, 1));
```

-->output

```
   2
   Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => world )
```

#### bad example:

```
$var ="The example number 2 is a bad example it will not 
count numbers  and punctuations !!";
```

-->output:

```
  14
  Array ( [0] => The [1] => example [2] => number [3] => is [4] => a
  [5] => bad [6] => example [7] => it [8] => will [9] => not 
  [10] => count [11] => numbers [12] => and [13] => punctuations )
```

Is there a good predefined function to do this properly or do I have to use preg_match() ?

Comment: poss use `white-space` to work out how many?

Comment: You could use `$words = explode(' ', $var);`

Comment: @TomKriek no this bad solution too since my input can have more than one space between 2 words.`print count(explode(' ', "hallo world"));//output 2
print count(explode(' ', "hallo   world"));` //output 3

Comment: sorry but the extra blanc was removed from my previous comment in the second example

Comment: Try this then  `$words = array_filter(explode(' ', $var));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always split your string by whitespace and count the results:

```
$res = preg_split('/\s+/', $input);
$count = count($res);
```

With your string

```
"The example number 2 is a bad example it will not 
count numbers  and punctuations !!"
```

This code will produce `16`.

The advantage of using this over `explode(' ', $string)` is that it will work on multi-line strings as well as tabs, not just spaces.  The disadvantage is that it's slower.

Comment: explode(' ', $string) will not always works because my data is stored in the database and I cannot tell if there is one or more space between two each words, But the first solution works always.

Answer (score 6):

The following using [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), will echo:

```
The number 1 in this line will counted and it contains the following count 8
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$text = "The number 1 in this line will counted";

$count = count(explode(" ", $text));

echo "$text and it contains the following count $count";

?>
```

---

**Edit:**

*Sidenote:*
The regex can be modified to accept other characters that are not included in the standard set.

```
<?php

$text = "The numbers   1  3 spaces and punctuations will not be counted !! . . ";

$text = trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $text));

$text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);


// used for the function to echo the line of text
$string = $text;

    function clean($string) {

       return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $string);

    }

echo clean($string);

echo "<br>";

echo "There are ";
echo $count = count(explode(" ", $text));
echo " words in this line, this includes the number(s).";

echo "<br>";

echo "It will not count punctuations.";

?>
```

Comment: works but with exception, if you add some extra space between your words the count will be increased

Comment: @Amani I see. Thanks for that and I'm glad to see that you've got your solution from Aleks, *cheers* :)

Comment: @Amani I've made an **Edit** which in this version, the extra spaces and punctuations will not be counted.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. +1 for the Edit

Comment: @Amani You're very much welcome. Please keep the accepted answer. I just wanted to make my answer better, since I did not initially take the potential extra spaces (and punctuations) into account. *Cheers* and thanks :) I hope it will also serve you well. It was a good question. +1

Answer (score 1):

The **most wide-spread method of counting words in a string** is by splitting with any kind of whitespace:

```
count(preg_split('~\s+~u', trim($text)))
```

Here, `'~\s+~u'` splits the whole text with any 1 or more Unicode whitespace characters.

**The disadvantage is that `!!` is considered a word.**

**In case you want to count letter and number words** (i.e. strings of text that are only made up of just letters or just numbers) you should consider a `preg_match_all` like

```
if (preg_match_all('~[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?|\d+|(?>\p{L}\p{M}*+)+~u', $text, $matches)) {
    return count($matches[0]);
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UUcDwF/5) and the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/UYSGk):

```
$re = '~[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?|\d+|(?>\p{L}\p{M}*+)+~u';
$text = "The example number 2 is a bad example it will not \ncount numbers  and punctuations !! X is 2.5674.";
if (preg_match_all($re, $text, $matches)) {
    echo count($matches[0]);
} // 18 in this string
```

The `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` regex is a well-known [integer or float number regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html), and `(?>\p{L}\p{M}*+)+` matches any 1 or more letters (`\p{L}`), each of which can be followed with any amount of diacritic marks (`\p{M}*+`).

**Regex details**

- `[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` - an optional `-` or `+`, 0+ ASCII digits, an optional `.`, 1+ ASCII digits, an optional sequence of `e` or `E`, an optional `-` or `+` and then 1+ ASCII digits
- `|` - or
- `\d+` - any 1 or more Unicode digits
- `|` - or
- `(?>\p{L}\p{M}*+)+` - 1 or more occurrences of any Unicode letter followed with any 0+ diacritic symbols.

**In case you just want to count text chunks consisting of solely digits and letters (with diacritics) *mixed up in any order***, you may also use

```
'~[\p{N}\p{L}\p{M}]+~u'
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UUcDwF/4), `\p{M}` matches diacritics, `\p{N}` matches digits and `\p{L}` matches letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `count(explode(' ', $var));`

Comment: this bad solution too since my input can have more than one space between 2 words.print count(explode(' ', "hallo world"));//output 2 print count(explode(' ', "hallo   world")); //output 3 PS second space in the second string is automatically removed from my comment

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the below code it's working for me.

```
    function get_num_of_words($string) {
        $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($string));
        $words = explode(" ", $string);
        return count($words);
    }

    $string="php string word count in simple way";
    echo $count=get_num_of_words($string);
```

The result will be 7

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, Still i m sharing the fix i have adopt for this.

```
$str ="Hello world !";
// you can include allowed special characters  as third param.
print_r(str_word_count($str, 1, '!'));
```

code output is

```
Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => world [2] => ! )
```

if you want to include more words u can specify as third param.

```
print_r(str_word_count($str, 1, '0..9.~!@#$%^&*()-_=+{}[]\|;:?/<>.,'));
```

from 0..9. will include all numbes, and other special characters are inserted individually.

Answer (score 0):

Just some improvement your solution

```
function stringWordNumberCount($text){
    if (!$text) {
        return 0;
    }

    //Clean the text to remove special character
    $text = trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $text));

    //Remove continus space on text
    $text = trim( preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$text));

    //count space
    return count(explode(' ', $text));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

ans:

```
function limit_text($text, $limit) {
    if(str_word_count($text, 0) > $limit) {
        $words = str_word_count($text, 2);
        $pos = array_keys($words);
        $text = substr($text, 0, $pos[$limit]) . '...';
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: if you using the class. you will add this.